# Updating a column variable using mysql and php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to update a column called attendance in my already existing database. Basically, I need to increment the count of attendance column in the database hosted on my server through my android application. Following is the code using Async, but it returns a nullpointer exception at onPostExecute.

```
package com.example.soumya.attendance;

public class RecordData extends Activity{



Button btnStartProgress;
ProgressDialog progressBar;
Double lati;
Double longi;
//  private ListView lvItem;
//private ArrayList<String> itemArrey;
//private ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;
int count = 0;
int attendance_count = 0;
TextView textView;
Boolean attendance = false;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();
GPSTracker gps;
private long fileSize = 0;
// Create the Handler object (on the main thread by default)
Handler handler = new Handler();
String final_msg="";
Handler progressHandler = new Handler();
// Define the code block to be executed
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something here on the main thread
        if(count<=6)
        {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getDateTime(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        count++;
        Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread");
        // Repeat this the same runnable code block again another 2 seconds
        //handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, (1 * 60) * 1000);
        handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 10 * 1000);
    }
};

public void Logout()
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        super.onDestroy();
}

public void update()
{
    final String update_url = "http://172.16.92.250/update.php";
    final String attendance = "1";
    final String uname = "aneesha";
    class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(RecordData.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            if (s.contains("success")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecordData.this, NewActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra(USER_NAME,username);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RecordData.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(update_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("attendance", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(attendance, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("uname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uname, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
    ulc.execute(attendance, uname);
}



  //  Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
  //  this.startActivity(intent);







public void receiveMyMessage() {
    Log.d("Textview", "found");
    final TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username3);
    Log.d("Textview", "Not found");
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify Views
            if (attendance_count == count) {
                txt.setText(final_msg+"\n\nYour attendance is marked!\nPlease logout");
                txt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));
               // BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
             //   backgroundTask.execute("update","1");
                Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        update();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                txt.setText(final_msg+"\n\nSorry, marked absent.\nPlease logout");
                txt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));

                //                  txt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(Color.RED));
            }
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Logout();
                }
            });

        }
    });  }
```

And following is update.php

```
    <?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'attendance');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','root');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$attendance = $POST['attendance'];
$uname = $POST['uname'];
$query = "UPDATE students SET attendance = ($attendance + attendance) WHERE uname = $uname");

result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0 )  
 {  
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "success";
 }
 else
 {echo "failed";}
 ?>
```

Comment: Is `result = mysqli_query($con, $query);` a typo? `result` not having a `$`, like so: `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);`?

Comment: Ditto for `$POST`. Should be `$_POST` in your `update.php` file.

Comment: Read up on superglobals http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and its syntax.

Comment: Your code btw, contains many syntax errors. Another being `WHERE uname = $uname");` unquoted string value. Then you're introducing the `mysqli_` API in with `mysql_`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: Not really! My problem is with java usage of mysql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you must correct your PHP. you're using

```
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
```

and

```
result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

mysql_connect  function and then you try to use mysqli_query

msqyl_* and mysqli_* are not compatible and can't be used at the same time, you either use:

- mysql_connect
- mysql_query
- mysql_num_rows
- mysql_fetch_assoc

or you use the mysqli ones:

- mysqli_connect
- mysqli_query
- mysqli_num_rows
- mysqli_fetch_assoc

also you're missing a $ in the result variable assign.

from the comments you can also change the $query assign to this:

```
$query = "UPDATE students SET attendance = ($attendance + attendance) WHERE uname = '$uname'");
```

and change $POST to $_POST

Hope this helps

Comment: mysql_* functions have been deprecated for more than 5 years, and are not present in current versions of PHP. You should not suggest anyone use them!

Comment: I don't suggest him to use it, I just point that they can't be mixed. I don't know what environment is using, maybe it's some old server that just needs an update and can't be migrated.

Comment: Your answer above says "you either use..." and then lists mysql_* functions, which is suggesting they be used. mysqli and PDO have been available since PHP 5.1 was released in 2005 so there is no excuse for not using them.

Comment: Yes, you either use one or the other but not both at the same time, when I say "I recomend using...." normally I will end that sentence with "PDO" :)